# Weird scenario with function pointer variable override

Tags: javascript

Consider this simple scenario:

```
(function x(){
  var foo = function(){
    console.log('foo is alive!');

    // set 'foo' variable to an empty function, using a delay
    setTimeout(function(){
      foo = function(){};
    },0);
  }

  foo();
  // calling 'foo' again, after it should be an empty function
  setTimeout(foo,100);
})();
```

If you would copy and run this code in your console, it would output `foo is alive!` twice. I am trying to understand why wouldn't `foo` gets overridden with the empty function. `foo` is clearly a variable which is being recognized inside the timeout callback, which points to the function.

**Boring background to this question:**
This is a simple test case for a more complex scenario I face using AJAX callbacks instead of a timeout which is used in this simple example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're launching `setTimeout()` function right away, passing it `foo()` *while it still exists* (is not empty), therefore it is actually available later, within the scope of `setTimeout()`.

Quick demo to achieve your expected result:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    foo();
}, 100);
```

(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0p7fgsso/ )

Here the `foo()` function is accessed only after it becomes an empty function. So nothing gets `console.log`-ged.

Comment: Interesting. I always thought it's the pointer which is passed, not the function itself Sadly this doesn't solve my real problem, which doesn't use any `setTimeout`...even weirder.

Comment: no, Actually this revelation does help me! this is insane to learn this after 10 years of coding js.